# Django missing data from database

Tags: python, django

Having a problem that shouldn't appear.
Created a django project. all the steps on windows OS.
Now when went to do everything the same on Ubuntu 20.04 then my index.html is not displaying any data from database even if there is a data ( i checked )

Html::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Django CRUD Operations</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Flight ID</th>
        <th>Aircraft</th>
        <th>Registration</th>
        <th>Latitude</th>
        <th>Longtitude</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for c in flight %}  
      <tr>
        <td>{{c.id}}</td>
        <td>{{c.aircraft}}</td>
        <td>{{c.registration}}</td>
        <td>{{c.latitude}}</td>
        <td>{{c.longtitude}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Views.py::

```
from .models import Flights
from django.shortcuts import render

def show(request):
    flights = Flights.objects.all()
    return render(request,"show.html",{'flight':flights})
```

Database is connected.
Any ideas? Maybe Ubuntu 20.04 has something that have to do differently like windows os?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is my settings.py :

```
"""
Django settings for djangoproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '******'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fly',
    'django',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'flight_radar_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Models.py::

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Flights(models.Model):
    aircraft = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    altitude = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ground_speed = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    longtitude = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    flying_from = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    flying_to = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    distance = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aircraft
```

Comment: It is hard to evaluate the problem from this. How is your settings file, particularly your db connection part? where is your db? is it a sqlite? Give us a bit more details and we might be able to help ;-)

Comment: Have you added any data to the flight table in the database? I know pretty basic, but ;-)

Comment: @rs_punia, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your access to flights object is wrong

as said [Here](https://fedingo.com/how-to-lookup-dictionary-value-with-key-in-django-template/) you must access it  like this

```
  {% for c in flights['flight'] %}  
  <tr>
    <td>{{c.id}}</td>
    <td>{{c.aircraft}}</td>
    <td>{{c.registration}}</td>
    <td>{{c.latitude}}</td>
    <td>{{c.longtitude}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

or you look it up like this

```
{% for key, value in flights %}
    <p> Value {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That would **not** work for the Django template engine (default template engine in Django), it will work with the Jinja template engine.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is so confusing, so one of the solutions right now is to change the default template engine ? Otherwise, I don't think it is a Ubuntu 20.04 problem, can-it be a missing package from the installation process?

Comment: The problem should not be with the template. I would guess the OP is using different databases in both the environments. If they want both to use the same database they need to configure their settings for that.

Comment: I’m thinking maybe because i copy pasted some lines of code when i was transfering from windows to linux maybe this causes the problem. Might try tomorrow to start everything from scratch and see if I’m getting any results

Answer (score 0):

Query the database using Django-shell, and test the data. Use `python3 manage.py shell`. In the shell:

```
from fly.models import Flights

flight_qs = Flights.objects.all()

for c in flight_qs:
    print(c.id)
```

If you see the results, there is no database issue then.

Comment: However, checked both on Windows and Linux it is working fine.

Comment: didn't quite understand where to insert this code you provided? tried to insert in the terminal that opens after python3 manage.py shell but this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, same in the terminal. Write `from fly.models import Flights`. It should work there.

Comment: I’ve just tested whole code you provided in shell and it gave me no results. Even if there is data in database. Hmm no idea why, I’ve deleted data from db, inserted again and still nothing. Should i just delete everything and start from scratch?

Comment: paste the code of your models.py

Comment: see my models in update

Comment: I’ve done everything from scratch and now everything is working fine. Don’t know what I’ve done wrong in first time but now it’s working. Thanks everyone who assisted

Comment: Good to know that, but pin pointing the exact fault would have been helpful for future readers.

Comment: i know this would be helpfull but i honestly don't know what went wrong as did exactly the same first time. Maybe some missing package that got an error.. no idea.